# How to interpret というか and だったり

Tags: meaning

From this paragraph:

> 中邑はかつての戦友たちの気持ちをおもんぱかりながらも「最近の日本のプロレスのスタイルというか、特に危険な技の応酬という意味では、そういうトレンドになっていた。本間さんの件もしかり、重傷者が出てきているということに考えたり、変える必要がある時期なんじゃないかな。各レスラーが今の危険な技だったり、リスクを顧みない試合について考えないといけない」と警鐘を鳴らした。

There are two things I don't understand:

-Is there some sort of connection between というか and という意味では in this line(I think he's talking about wrestling style as a whole but then kind of backs down):

> 「最近の日本のプロレスのスタイル**というか**、特に危険な技の応酬**という意味では**、そういうトレンドになっていた。

-And this line(Is it saying that nowadays each wrestler possess dangerous moves?):

> 各レスラーが今の危険な技だったり

Answer (score 2, accepted):

というか is a word used before trying to rephrase/re-explain something. It's close to "or rather" or "I mean" in English.

～という意味では literally means "in the sense of ～", but here you can roughly translate this as "as far as ～ goes", "if you mean ～", or "speaking of ～", etc.

So he first tried to say 最近の日本のプロレスのスタイルという意味では ("regarding the recent style of Japanese pro wrestling"), but stopped saying it in the middle and rephrased it to something more specific, 危険な技の応酬という意味では.

> 最近の日本のプロレスのスタイルというか、特に危険な技の応酬という意味では、そういうトレンドになっていた。
>   Speaking of the recent style of Japanese pro wrestling... I mean, (speaking of) the exchange of dangerous moves in particular, (yes, certainly,) there have been such a trend.

And this sentence:

> 各レスラーが今の危険な技だったり、リスクを顧みない試合について考えないといけない。
>   Each wrestler must (re)think about (things like) dangerous moves and reckless games these days. (lit. "games about which you don't consider risks")

だったり/であったり is just another way to list nouns and na/no-adjectives non-exhaustively. It's basically the famous `verb + たり + verb (+ たり)` construction, except that the copula だ is used instead of normal verbs. 各レスラー is the subject of 考えないといけない. 今の危険な技 is a noun phrase meaning "dangerous moves (found) these days." If you were disturbed by the comma after だったり, please keep in mind that [Japanese commas have very little grammatical role](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/40194/5010).

Comment: I'm trying really hard to understand  the だ　in 危険な技だったり but it seems weird . Is there another way to rephrase that part? I mean is it really necessary to have a verb after  危険な技? why not 危険な技と like in "A と B について考えないといけない"??

Comment: 危険な技**や**リスクを顧みない試合について考えないといけない is basically the same. 危険な技**と**リスクを顧みない試合について考えないといけない sounds a bit different because of the reason explained [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17383/5010). だったり looks similar to the past-form (ta-form), but many people simply regard it as the [tari-form of the copula](https://goo.gl/X1aevi). Semantically it's not related to the past tense. Finally, たり usually has to be used twice or more in a "well-written" sentence, but the second たり is sometimes omitted. Please see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4793/5010).