# Should I replace commas with と in Japanese?

Tags: grammar, particle-と, punctuation

I have seen many times sentences that connect many objects with と which in English would require comma. So, is it better to generally just replace comma with と whenever connecting many things together?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/474/the-many-ways-to-say-and-in-japanese This may answer the question.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3786/usage-of-commas-in-japanese-sentences